# Ternary Operator on C#

Tags: c#

I need help, the next code works:

```
class A{}
class B:A{}
class C:A{}

A a;
if (Console.ReadLine() == "A")
    a = new B();
else
    a = new C();
```

Then why this doesn't:

```
A a = (Console.ReadLine() == "A") ? new B() : new C();
```

Comment: Because they return different types.With a cast it would work: `A a = (Console.ReadLine() == "A") ? (A)new B() : (A)new C();`

Comment: Just one of the `(A)` would be sufficient I suspect @AlexanderDerck.

Comment: From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator): *"The type of consequence and alternative must be the same, or there must be an **implicit conversion** from one type to the other."*